# No puedo pillar las datos del formulario completo con beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, requests

Quiero pillar los nombre y los precios de todos los videojuegos que estan en la busqueda. Al realizar el .get y probar el print en la variable lista me reconoce todos los datos pero luego al iterar, no me los reconoce en el for loop.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.instant-gaming.com/es/juegos/steam/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lista = soup.find_all ('div', class_='search')
    
for i in lista:
    nombre = i.find('div', class_='name')
    precio = i.find('div', class_= 'price')
    info = [nombre, precio]
    print (info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que estas cometiendo es buscar por la *class* *'search'*, ya que solo hay un elemento que posee esa clase. Sí bien es correcto que dentro de search, se encuentren todos los items. Estos mismos están asociados a la *class* *'item force-badge'*.

Voy a utilizar tu código para hacer algunas modificaciones mínimas y verás como se soluciona:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.instant-gaming.com/es/juegos/steam/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lista = soup.find_all ('div', class_='item force-badge')    
info = []
for i in lista:
    nombre = i.find('div', class_='name').get_text(strip=True)
    precio = i.find('div', class_= 'price').get_text(strip=True)
    info.append({'nombre':nombre, 
                 'precio':precio})
```

Agregué una lista llamada `info`, en la cual en cada vuelta del loop, estará insertando un diccionario con los resultados deseados, *precio* y *nombre*. utilizo `.get_text()`, para extraer el texto plano.

El resultado final es un *DataFrame* `info`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(info)
df.head()
```

| nombre | precio |
| --- | --- |
| Dying Light 2 Stay Human | $60.40 |
| Elden Ring | $49.85 |
| God of War | $38.39 |
| Monster Hunter Rise | $43.89 |
| Farming Simulator 22 | $28.64 |